# Como redirecionar para uma ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

por problemas de conflito entre duas frameworks, tive que passar o código de login do facebook para uma classe auxiliar, entretanto não estou sabendo como redirecionar o usuário para a tela principal do app após o login estiver realizado, Alguém ai consegue me dar uma solução para isso?

```
  @IBAction func loginFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {
    let util = Util()
    util.loginFacebook()
}
 /*Método na classe util*/
func loginFacebook(){
    let permission = ["public_profile"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permission)
    let requisicao = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters:["fields":"id, name, gender,age_range, email"])

    requisicao.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)


        }else if let resultado = result{
            let dados = resultado as! NSDictionary
            // redirecionar para pagina principal junto com os dados
        }



    }
```

Comment: basta voce usar o método `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "coloca_aqui_o_ID_da_segue", sender: nil)` que ele vai pro ViewController determinado pela ID da segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você retira o método do ViewController e coloca em uma classe separada você perde o "self", por isso não pode simplesmente chamar self.performSegueWithIdentifier().

O que você pode fazer é mudar a assinatura do método para

```
func loginFacebook(viewController: UIViewController)
```

Com isto, quando você chamar este método desde qualquer viewController você passa como parâmetro self:

```
Util.loginFacebook(self)
```

Dentro da implementação de loginFacebook você precisa chamar o performSegue da seguinte forma:

```
func loginFacebook(viewController: UIViewController) {
    ...
    }else if let resultado = result{
        let dados = resultado as! NSDictionary
        // redirecionar para pagina principal junto com os dados
        viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: viewController)
    }
```